# execute bash script from php without waiting

Tags: php, bash

I execute a bash script from php with shell_exec.
But the php script waits until the shell script is finished.

Can I somehow call the bash script without waiting.
Both:

```
exec
shell_exec
```

are waiting until the bash script is finished.
I'm running linux btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to work:

`exec('/your/command /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`

Comment: ok almost the final solution was  `sh command > /dev/null 2>&1 &` thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

when calling your bash script append & so it will run in the background
that's the easiest way if you don't need any output

```
shell_exec("/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh &");
```

Comment: what exactly did not work? the running in the background? the script? maybe it is a permission problem

Comment: php was still waiting until the script was executed. "sh command > /dev/null 2>&1 &" did the trick though. thanks for your help :)